# Close PayPal lightbox and Reload Parent Page by Removing Frames in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, paypal

I am using PayPal embedded payment flow with a lightbox:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

Once payment is complete, the user is directed to a success URL.  On the success URL, I have a script that is supposed replace the top window content with the content of the success URL:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/ClosingWindow/

My code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (window != top) {
        top.location.replace(document.location);
    }
})
```

This works great in Chrome, Opera, and Firefox.  The problem is that in IE 11 and Edge, the PPDG frame remains, which prevents my page from loading full screen.  I have tried using closeFlow() in various ways such as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    dgFlow = top.dgFlow || top.opener.top.dgFlow;
    dgFlow.closeFlow();
    if (window != top) {
        top.location.replace(document.location);
    }
})
```

However, I can't seem to get it to work properly in IE or Edge.

Here is the code I am using to call the embedded flow:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay" target="PPDGFrame" class="standard">
    <input type="image" id="submitBtn" value="Pay with PayPal" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif">
    <input id="type" type="hidden" name="expType" value="light">
    <input id="paykey" type="hidden" name="paykey" value=@ViewData["paykey"]></form>
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js"></script>
<script>var dgFlow = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({ trigger: 'submitBtn' });</script>
```

Is there anyone who can help me make this work in IE and Edge?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured this out using window.opener.  Thus, it seems my working code for Edge, IE 11, Chrome, FF, and Opera is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.opener) { // check if opened in popup
        window.close();
    }
    if (window != top) {
        top.location.replace(document.location);
    }
})
```

So far so good.......

Comment: top.location.replace(document.location); working for me ! Thanks !